# Tablix border when tablix split across two pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've got the following SSRS report, which when exported to PDF the tablix splits across multiple pages, which is fine, however, I don't want the left and right border lines to carry on over, the cell itself doesn't split, its the tablix. Can this be prevented?

[image]

Comment: Remove the border on the tablix and only have the borders on the detail rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as a solution, since this worked for you!

```
Remove the border on the tablix and only have the borders on the detail rows.
```

Glad it worked!